# What GUI library for medical devices?

Tags: c, user-interface, embedded

I've read about TouchGFX, Embedded Wizard, emWin, Qt, Crack Storyboard, Altia GUI, uGFX and ThreadX GUIX.

Does anyone here have experience with the usage of these options in the medical industry ?

[example interfaces](https://postimg.cc/gallery/TDkvcfs)

What do big companies, such as GE Healthcare, Philips Healthcare, Siemens Healthineers use ?

Thanks

Comment: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" is not suited for SO

Comment: Given that this question is programming-related, where should I ask ?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time researching this same question (for a dialysis machine).

The answer that I got from almost every vendor I could find is that you can run any GUI software you like but you run it on a processor that is not part of your safety case.  This is really frustrating I know.

The kind of GUIs that have enough testing and documentation to put in a regulatory submission are very basic.

One that was suggested was "Qt Safe Renderer", which was developed for car dashboards.  It runs on top of normal Qt.  The majority of the GUI would use normal Qt which is not developed to any safety standard, and then the safe renderer just provides a frame overlay buffer that can draw on top of the main GUI.  It is meant for putting things like "engine overheating" icons onto the display.  The idea is that even if the main GUI fails (which is legally required to be assumed to have 100% probablity in IEC62304) and it stops updating or draws rubbish, then the high priority icon will still be overlayed onto it.  If you want it to do something more complicated than bit-blit a basic icon then they will offer to implement specific functions for you but the cost will be incredible!

I suggest you just google and phone every company you can find.  All the big ones have sales reps desperate to give you a presentation.  They will probably want an NDA in place before they give you the details that you really need though.

Answer (score 0):

dont know what big companies use
me using qt / vtk